# Telerik WPF RibbonBar populated via DataBinding

Tags: wpf, data-binding, telerik, ribbon, recursive-databinding

I have and object model, a UserProfile, that contains many ServiceProfile, each containing many CommandProfile.
I have bound this model with Telerik WPF OutlookBar:

```
<telerikNavigation:RadOutlookBar

                                ItemsSource="{Binding ServiceProfiles}"
                                Background="{Binding Color}">
                                <telerikNavigation:RadOutlookBar.TitleTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Label Content="{Binding Description}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </telerikNavigation:RadOutlookBar.TitleTemplate>
                                <telerikNavigation:RadOutlookBar.ItemTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <Label Content="{Binding Description}"/>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </telerikNavigation:RadOutlookBar.ItemTemplate>
                                <telerikNavigation:RadOutlookBar.ContentTemplate>
                                    <DataTemplate>
                                        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding CommandProfiles}" Background="Transparent">
                                            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                                <DataTemplate>
                                                    <Button 
                                                        Content="{Binding Description}"
                                                        Command="{Binding ExecuteCommand}"
                                                        />
                                                </DataTemplate>
                                            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                                        </ListBox>
                                    </DataTemplate>
                                </telerikNavigation:RadOutlookBar.ContentTemplate>
                            </telerikNavigation:RadOutlookBar>
```

This XAML code creates a OutlookbarItem for each ServiceProfile. Each OutlookbarItem presents a list of buttons as a content.

I'm not able to do the analogous job with ribbonBar: inside a single tab (referring to my UserProfile), I want to create a RibbonGroup for each ServiceProfile. Inside each Group (Service profile) there are many Ribbonbuttons, one for each CommandProfile.
But I'm not able.

I arrive to this code:

```
 <telerikRibbonBar:RadRibbonTab 
                x:Name="theTab"
                Header="{Binding Description}" 
                Background="{Binding Color}"
                ItemsSource="{Binding ServiceProfiles}">

            </telerikRibbonBar:RadRibbonTab>
```

which creates the ribbongroups, but I'm not able to control anything (title of the group, fill (via Binding) the content.

Any idea?

Thanks

```
Marco Parenzan
```

Answer (score 0):

Bit late, but sorry to say but it doesn't look supported yet:

http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/silverlight/ribbonbar/headertemplate-of-radribbontab.aspx

> Hello Alex Fan,
>
> Unfortunately the RibbonBar doesn't support databinding for now. However, you can put your vote for this feature in our PITS thus increasing its priority.
>
> In your case the best will be if you add the ribbon items programmatically. 
>
> Let us know if you need more info.
>
> All the best,
> Tina Stancheva 
> the Telerik team